# What is the right way to update git repository, after somebody pushed into it?

Tags: git

For example, if I cloned a repository `A` to some other remote location (`B`) over ssh, edited in `B`, committed, then executed

```
git push A
```

When I go back to `A`, I see that it is now at the latest pushed revision, but it also has some changes staged - the direct opposite of that commit in `B`, actually. I usually work around it by using

```
git checkout -f master
```

but the "-f" flag makes me nervous - for example, there could be some useful changes staged, that I carelessly throw away by doing this checkout.

What am I doing wrong? Is there some better way of doing push/update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intended command would be "git pull" rather than the "git checkout"

If you have changes that are not committed, you should. This will save the changes that you have and get the new updates.  Finally reapply the changes that you originally saved.

```
git stash
git pull
git stash pop
```

If you have local commits that you have not pushed yet, you can do.  This will rewind your changes apply what was pushed and reapply the commits.

```
git pull --rebase
```

You can just do "git pull" with the commits but that will add a merge commit, that in my opinion dirties the history and can cause some problems.

I generally do not like the -force option for the reason that you stated.  You don't want to lose anything useful.

Comment: The problem is, at the moment I needed to move changes from B to A, I couldn't directly do "git pull" from A (for example, B is on wireless laptop somewhere in undefined location, from which I need to move changes to A on server)

Comment: Doing the "git push" from B should update A that changes have occurred.  I am not sure that I understand your problem...

Comment: It *does* update. But it doesn't update the working directory for some reason, leaving the negation of differences before the push and after the push in the staging area.

Comment: How is it that you are finding the differences?  You should still need to pull when you log into A.  The negation could be because you are checking where A's current status is versus where the most up-to-date changes are.

Comment: `git pull: fatal: Where do you want to fetch from today?` - I can't pull, since the machine that did the push is offline already.

Comment: What does git status say?  Is it showing that your files are modified?

Comment: Yes, it shows that files were modified. For example, if I created a file in B, in A `git status` says that file was deleted (since the file is physically non-existent, because the repository hasn't updated to latest version)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19230/discussion-between-schleis-and-rogach)

Answer (score 2):

I think the root problem is that you are `git push`ing to a non-bare repository that has a checked out working copy. I'm surprised `git` doesn't whine about this, but maybe you have an older version of `git` or you have configured it not to complain. `git push` will update the remote repository, but not the remote working copy, so when you then look at `A`, the working copy contents correspond to some previous revision, while the repository has been updated. Obviously there are differences between the two. In this case `git checkout -f` is probably your best option (or `git reset --hard HEAD`), followed by converting your `A` repository to a bare one.

Comment: We already figured it out (in discussion with Schleis) - I have recieve.denycurrentbranch set to warn instead of error.